# BigQuery SQL: Add line break in concatenate string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to concatenate a string:

```
concat(product," (",cast(created_date as string)," - ",cast(end_date as string),") ")
```

in Output I get :

```
Row           String
1       Product_B (12-02-2020 - 21-04-2020)
2       Product_A (10-01-2020 - 11-02-2020)
3       Product_C (14-05-2020 - 19-07-2020)
```

So I want to add a line break in concatenate string
And as a result, receive:

```
Row              String
1               Product_B 
           (12-02-2020 - 21-04-2020)
2               Product_A
           (10-02-2020 - 11-02-2020)
3               Product_C  
           (14-05-2020 - 19-07-2020)
```

What needs to be added to get break a string line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below option

```
select *,
  format('%s\n(%s - %s)', product, created_date, end_date) rip
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question -

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (                
  select 'Product_B' product, '2020-02-12' created_date, '2020-04-21' end_date union all
  select 'Product_A', '2020-01-10', '2020-02-11' union all
  select 'Product_C', '2020-05-14', '2020-07-19' 
)
```

output is

[image]

In case if your dates column are of DATE data type - use below instead

```
select *,
  format('%s\n(%t - %t)', product, created_date, end_date) rip
from `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `\n`:

```
select concat("a","\n","c")
```

or

```
select "a\nc"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sergey. To extend your answer you can use \n\n to generate a blank line between the strings.